# Does fread() behave different on different endian machine?

Tags: c, endianness, fread

I am reading the header of a bmp file. My system and bmp file values are both in little endian format. So I read as below:

```
uint32_t fileSize;
fread(&fileSize,1,4,bmpFile);
```

In bmp file, these bytes are ordered as: ... 36 04 01 00 ...
The resulting value of the fileSize is 66614 which is:  0x00010436.
I get the correct value and there is no problem.

However something bothers me. Does this code work similarly for a big endian machine or does fread() behave differently and I get 0x36040100 incorrectly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`fread` reads the data "as is" into memory, therefore your code will definitely behave differently on a big endian CPU than on a little endian CPU.

In other words `fread` does not know that you are reading a `uint32_t`. All `fread` knows is that you want to read 4 bytes to the memory location where the `fileSize` variable lives.

Comment: Then my code will return 0x36040100 in a big endian machine, right?

Answer (score 1):

`fread()` in your program reads `36` `04` `01` `00` bytes to int32 `fileSize` variable. Since your CPU is little endian which actually reads bytes from left to right as `00` `01` `04` `36` rather right to left. Therefore when you read a binary file you must convert form the file format endianess to your system CPU endianess.